# Переключение на новую tabPages

Tags: c#

Всем привет скажите у меня есть код

```
private void новыйФайлToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rich = new RichTextBox();
            rich.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rich.Visible = true;

            tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Новый " + tabControl1.TabCount);
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(rich);
        }
```

У меня на новой странице должен создаваться richTextBox, но только на ВЫБРАННОЙ, а как сделать чтобы при создании было переключение на новую страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string name = "Новый " + tabControl1.TabCount;
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(name, name);
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[name];
tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(rich);
```

Comment: Ошибка
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Исправил код